# Linq JS grouping objects with there name first letter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, linq

```
list = [
    {
        "Id": "547370FD-5185-47F7-B980-C439A010E028",

        "FirstName": "Rahul",
        "LastName": "Grag"
    },
    {

        "Id": "547370FD-5185-47F7-B980-C439A010E027",
        "FirstName": "Mohit",
        "LastName": "V"
    },
    {

        "Id": "547370FD-5185-47F7-B980-C439A010E026",
        "FirstName": "Sanjeev",
        "LastName": "Kumar"
    },
    {

        "Id": "547370FD-5185-47F7-B980-C439A010E025",
        "FirstName": "Manish",
        "LastName": "Kumar"
    },
    {

        "Id": "547370FD-5185-47F7-B980-C439A010E024",
        "FirstName": "Rahul",
        "LastName": "Jain"
    },
    {

        "Id": "547370FD-5185-47F7-B980-C439A010E023",
        "FirstName": "Shikha",
        "LastName": "K"
    }
];
```

I need to group this objects with respect to there `FirstName` first letter.
How can i do it?

Comment: group or sort ?? can you provide your expected output and your efforts ?

Answer (score 1):

This will create an object where the key is the first letter of a name. The value is a array of all list objects whose FirstName has the same first letter.

```
var names = {};

list.forEach(function(obj) {
  if (!obj.FirstName || !obj.FirstName.length) return;

  var firstLetter = obj.FirstName[0];

  if (!names[firstLetter]) {
    names[firstLetter] = [];
  }
  names[firstLetter].push(obj);
});
```

If you are not sure of whether the first letter of the firstName will be a capital, you could always do `firstLetter.toUpperCase()` to enforce that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/), it's trivial.

```
var query = Enumerable.From(list).GroupBy("$.FirstName[0]");
```